# mySql query group by with order by date not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables like this
 and I want latest data by date

```
tbl_fruit_info
+-----+--------+
| sId | sName  |
+-----+--------+
|   1 | Apple  |
|   2 | Banana |
|   3 | Orange |
+-----+--------+

tbl_fruit_data
+------------+----------+-------------+
|    date    | fruit_id | fruit_price |
+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017-01-26 |        1 | 44.7        |
| 2017-01-27 |        1 | 51          |
| 2017-01-25 |        1 | 71.5        |
| 2017-01-21 |        2 | 44          |
| 2017-01-23 |        2 | 55          |
| 2017-01-24 |        2 | 71          |
+------------+----------+-------------+
```

I tried with this

```
                    SELECT tbl_fruit_info.*, tbl_fruit_data.*
                    FROM tbl_fruit_data 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        tbl_fruit_info ON tbl_fruit_info.sId = tbl_fruit_data.fruit_id 
                    GROUP BY 
                        tbl_fruit_info.sId
                    ORDER BY 
                        max(tbl_fruit_data.date) DESC;
```

The Output I am looking for is like this:

```
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
| sId | sName  | date          |fruit_price | 
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
|   1 | Apple  | 2017-01-27    | 51         |
|   2 | Banana | 2017-01-24    | 71         |
|   3 | Orange | 0000-00-00    | 0          |
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
```

But I get this:

```
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
| sId | sName  | date          |fruit_price | 
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
|   1 | Apple  | 2017-01-26    | 44.7       |
|   2 | Banana | 2017-01-21    | 44         |
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either you are looking for max or min. confirm that frst

Comment: I want latest data by date

Comment: Edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tbl_fruit_data f
    left join tbl_fruit_info i ON i.sId = f.fruit_id 
where f.Date =
    (Select max(date) from tbl_fruit_data
     where fruit_id = f.fruit_id)
```

Comment: You forgot the closing paranthehis in max(date*)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fi.*, fd.*
FROM tbl_fruit_data fd
  FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_fruit_info fi ON fi.sId = fd.fruit_id
WHERE fd.fruit_id IS NULL OR fd.date = (
  SELECT max(fd_inner.date)
  FROM tbl_fruit_data fd_inner
  WHERE fd_inner.fruit_id = fd.fruit_id
) 
ORDER BY fd.date DESC;
```

Update 2017-01-30: Incorporates rows in tbl_fruit_info that don't have a corresponding row in tbl_fruit_data, now.

Comment: It works nice but I want all element of tbl_fruit_info as well. Please consider the output table  I want!

Comment: Answer updated. You might have to tweak order and displaying of missing values a bit to meet your demands.

Comment: @AsimKrishnaDas If this "works nice" then you must have mis-tagged the question. Because this ISN'T MySQL

Comment: What is it within the query that does not work with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes.

**Get the *latest* prices on fruit, ADDED fruits not having a price

```
SELECT d1.date, d1.fruit_id, d1.fruit_price, i.sId, i.sName 
FROM tbl_fruit_info i
LEFT JOIN tbl_fruit_data d1
ON d1.fruit_id = i.sId
WHERE d1.date = (SELECT MAX(d2.date) 
                FROM tbl_fruit_data d2
                WHERE d2.fruit_id = d1.fruit_id
                 )
UNION
SELECT CAST('0001-01-01' AS datetime) date, i.sId fruit_id, 0 fruit_price, i.sId, i.sName
FROM tbl_fruit_info i
WHERE i.sId NOT IN (SELECT d2.fruit_id FROM tbl_fruit_data d2)
```

**Sql fiddle for test on the same data provides in question:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/872ed4/9

**Used these definitions**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_fruit_info
    (`sId` int, `sName` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO tbl_fruit_info
    (`sId`, `sName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Apple'),
    (2, 'Banana'),
    (3, 'Orange')
;


CREATE TABLE tbl_fruit_data
    (`date` datetime, `fruit_id` int, `fruit_price` int)
;

INSERT INTO tbl_fruit_data
    (`date`, `fruit_id`, `fruit_price`)
VALUES
    ('2017-01-26 00:00:00', 1, 44.7),
    ('2017-01-27 00:00:00', 1, 51),
    ('2017-01-25 00:00:00', 1, 71.5),
    ('2017-01-21 00:00:00', 2, 44),
    ('2017-01-23 00:00:00', 2, 55),
    ('2017-01-24 00:00:00', 2, 71)
;
```

Comment: You did really well. Actually I want all the fruit price that is not in data table

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Note that all tables in an RDBMS should have a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Each of your tables lacks a PRIMARY KEY. That's all.

Comment: I'm not explaining good database design, just creating sample data to fiddle with in order to give an answer to the question... But yes, good design is to have primary keys, handle null values if wanted, consider datatypes etc...

Comment: It goes deeper than that. It impacts upon the validity of your answer. There is a tacit assumption in your answer that fruits in one table, and fruits and dates in the other table are unique. You should make that implicit assumption explicit in the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Using dadde's fiddle (with some tweaks) - and assuming that the MySQL tag is correct...

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_fruit_info
    (`sId` int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `sName` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO tbl_fruit_info
    (`sId`, `sName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Apple'),
    (2, 'Banana'),
    (3, 'Orange')
;


CREATE TABLE tbl_fruit_data
    (`date` datetime, `fruit_id` int, `fruit_price` int, primary key (fruit_id,date))
;

INSERT INTO tbl_fruit_data
    (`date`, `fruit_id`, `fruit_price`)
VALUES
    ('2017-01-26 00:00:00', 1, 44.7),
    ('2017-01-27 00:00:00', 1, 51),
    ('2017-01-25 00:00:00', 1, 71.5),
    ('2017-01-21 00:00:00', 2, 44),
    ('2017-01-23 00:00:00', 2, 55),
    ('2017-01-24 00:00:00', 2, 71)
;

SELECT a.sid
     , a.sname
     , COALESCE(b.date,'0000-00-00') date
     , COALESCE(b.fruit_price,0) fruit_price 
  FROM tbl_fruit_info a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM tbl_fruit_data x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT fruit_id, MAX(date) date 
         FROM tbl_fruit_data 
        GROUP 
           BY fruit_id
     ) y 
    ON y.fruit_id = x.fruit_id 
   AND y.date = x.date) b 
    ON b.fruit_id = a.sid;
+-----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| sid | sname  | date                | fruit_price |
+-----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
|   1 | Apple  | 2017-01-27 00:00:00 |          51 |
|   2 | Banana | 2017-01-24 00:00:00 |          71 |
|   3 | Orange | 0000-00-00          |           0 |
+-----+--------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
create table #t1
(id int,name varchar(100));


create table #t2(
[date] date,
id int,
price float)

insert into #t1
select 1,'Apple'
union
select 2,'Banana'

insert into #t2
select getdate()-3,1,33.2
union
select getdate()-2,1,30.5
union
select getdate()-4,1,23.4
union
select getdate()-3,2,21
union
select getdate()-2,2,35
```

Query

```
select q.name,t2.* from (
select  t1.id,t1.name,MAX(t2.date) as date from #t1 t1
inner join #t2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
group by t1.id,t1.name
) as q inner join #t2 t2
on q.id=t2.id and t2.date=q.date
```

Edit: Fixed, replaced CTE with subquery, thanks dadde for pointing out CTE isn't supported in MySQL. CTE or Subquery does the same job here

Comment: isnt that tsql?

Comment: true, its T-SQL but idea remains the same. doing a group by in inner query and joining with main table to get the required details from other table.

Comment: Does tsql not have decimal data type